# SOQL - how to include fields from the grand parent object in the WHERE cleause

Tags: soql

I'm carrying out a query on Quote object. A Quote has an Opportunity which has an Account. Both Quote and Account objects have the field `Vat_Rate__c`. I'd like to run a query that returns all quotes where the `Vat_Rate__c` on the Quote and Account don't match.

I thought the following would work:

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM Quote WHERE Vat_Rate__c !=: Opportunity.Account.Vat_Rate__c
```

But this returns the error:

> Unknown error parsing query

The following query runs without error:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Opportunity.Account.Vat_Rate__c FROM Quote LIMIT 1
```

So I know the field `Opportunity.Account.Vat_Rate__c` is referenced correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use a formula field for the comparison. SOQL does not support field comparisons.

Comment: Field to field comparison is not allowed which you are doing in your query. 
Link for your reference- https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000187460&language=en_US&type=1#:~:text=Salesforce%20does%20not%20allow%20direct,use%20in%20a%20WHERE%20clause.